# How to find first three characters in a char[] arr Java

Tags: java

How find if the first three characters in a `char[] seqarr` are `A/a, T/t, G/g` in this order (case insensitive) in Java

I tried this

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
    if(seqarr[i] == 'A'|| seqarr[i] == 'a' ||seqarr[i] ==  'T' ||seqarr[i] ==  't'|| seqarr[i] == 'G'|| seqarr[i] == 'g' ){
        return true;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It *is* easier to work with a String, but unnecessary: you can simply work with the individual characters, uppercasing them to normalize for case:

```
return arr.length >= 3
    && Character.toUpperCase(arr[0]) == 'A'
    && Character.toUpperCase(arr[1]) == 'T'
    && Character.toUpperCase(arr[2]) == 'G';
```

This avoids creating any objects, so will likely be faster than converting to `String`.

You could also just be explicit about the upper and lower case variants:

```
(arr[0] == 'A' || arr[0] == 'a')
```

Instead of `Character.toUpperCase` etc. The downside of that is that it's easy to make a mistake in getting the correct upper/lowercase pairs when you copy and paste (as demonstrated in @Tim's comment below: `A/t`, rather than `A/a`).

Comment: When I first answered, the OP was not clear to me (and a few of the other answers).  We thought that the OP wanted to check for the sequence `A/t` or `T/t` or `G/g`, in which case working with a string would be much more attractive +1

Answer (score 2):

This would be *much* easier to handle if you were working with strings instead of character arrays.  The reason for this is that using your current approach you will need to check each of the three individual characters, three times, for each starting pattern.  That being said, one way to approach this would be to convert the character array back to a string and do the check there:

```
public boolean isValid(char[] array) {
    if (array.length < 3) {
        return false;
    }
    // create string from only first 3 characters of array
    String str = new String(array, 0, 3);
    return str.equalsIgnoreCase("atg");
}

char[] array = {'A', 't', 'G', 'c', '/', 'C', 'G'}; // ... and more data
isValid(array);
```

This approach should perform well because it avoids creating a lengthy string from a character array.  All we need are the first three characters in order to perform the check.

Comment: Using `equalsIgnoreCase` is better than explicitly calling `toLowerCase`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `String` instead of a char array and use `indexOf` method.

```
String s = new String(seqarr);
s = s.toLowerCase();
System.out.println(s.indexOf("atg") == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `copyValueOf` from `String` to convert the `char` array to `String`. Then use `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare.

```
public boolean isValid(char[] seqarr) {
    return String.copyValueOf(seqarr, 0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase("atg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, then you want to find if the first three characters are either `ATG` or not, in the right order, like

```
ATGsomething
aTGsomething
AtGsomething
Atgsomething
...
```

Then you can do this using regular expressions as well

```
String str = String.valueOf(seqarr);
if(str.matches("^[Aa][Tt][Gg]")) {
    return true;
}
```

---

You can also do it by tweaking your code a little bit

```
if( seqarr.length>=3 && (seqarr[0] == 'A'|| seqarr[0] == 'a') && (seqarr[1] ==  'T' ||seqarr[1] ==  't') && (seqarr[2] == 'G'|| seqarr[2] == 'g' ){
    return true;
```